# Is my method of adding Google Banner to my view controller memory safe?

Tags: ios, objective-c, reference-counting

In the Google Admob/DFP tutorial [1] they recommend to use the bannerView as instance variable , but I don't them to pollute my viewcontroller class, so I have a `Util` class, has a method that return an autoreleased DFPBannerView

```
- (DFPBannerView *) getBannerAds
{
  DFPBannerView * bannerView;
  bannerView = [[[DFPBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait] autorelease];
  ...
  return bannerView;
}
```

And in my all of my view controller classes, if I want to add banner into the view...

```
DFPBannerView * bannerView = [self getBannerAds];
[self.view addSubview: bannerView];
```

Questions:

1. Is my method memory safe, are there any memory leak? (I am not using ARC)

[1] https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/dfp/fundamentals

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the code is fine in terms of memory handling in a manual referenced counted environment. (i.e. not ARC)

getBannerAds is returning an autoreleased object, which is correct.

When you add the subview using view addSubview, self.view will retain the bannerView for as long as it needs it and then be responsible for releasing it too.